# How to know how many Facebook likes did I get?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I want to know how many likes did I get in Facebook. Includes my comments, posts, shares...

Are there any way to count?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,
commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="[INSERT YOUR URL HERE]"`

For more information visit:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/